# How do I add two separate data into one record?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok... so I get :title and :content with form_for helper and save them in my model, post.

However, I want to give a random nickname for everyone who posted.

I've made a simple Namemaker, but don't know how to add this data along with each post.

(1) This is a code for form_for (:title, :content)

```
<section class = 'form' id = 'main_form'>
<p>
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>

<div class = 'form_input'>
    <%= f.text_field :title, style: "width: 70%; color: black;", placeholder: 'Write your title' %> <br>
    <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 10, style: "width: 70%; color:black;", placeholder: 'Write your content.' %> <br>
</div>

<div class = 'form_submit'>
    <%= f.submit('Submit!') %>
</div>

<% end %> 
</p>
```

(2) This is a code for my random Namemaker

```
  pre = ['gentle', 'funny', 'sleepy', 'horny', 'stupid']
  suff = ['crocodile', 'lion', '9gager', 'cat', 'dog']
  name = pre[rand(4)] + suff[rand(4)]
```

How should I add this 'name' with the data from form_for each time? 
Where should I put them? should I make a new action in controller?

Summary in a line: What would you do if you had to give a random name to each one's post, after getting :title / :content with 'form_for' ?
This is essentially what i'm asking

Comment: you just need to display the random nickname or save them for future displays?

Comment: Hmm I just want to display the random name on each post. If that doesn't require saving, then I can go without saving them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to add a custom name to post params in the controller create action. If you are using strong params (which you should use). It will look like this:

```
def create
  post = Post.new(post_params.merge(name: your_random_name))
  if post.save?
    # ...
end
```

Another way is to use `before_create` callback:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  before_create :generate_name

  def generate_name
    self.name = your_random_name
  end
  # ...
end
```